# Operating with very small numbers

Tags: matlab

I want to do a subtraction 1-x, where x is a very small number(Order of magnitude of -19 or-20).I do not get the number I want: after the operation the number is still 1.

I know that's because Matlab only calculates to 53 bits which allows to operations up to 1E-16, but is there an alternative method to solve this kind of operations?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit more about why you need this, what you will do with this number that is so close to 1? The answer might depend on that...

Comment: If you really need to represent that number: use either a [symbolic](https://es.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/create-symbolic-numbers-variables-and-expressions.html) or a [high-precision floating-point](https://es.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36534-hpf-a-big-decimal-class) representation

Comment: [matlab's vpa](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html)

Comment: I still think that it is probably better to translate the problem to the origin, rather than use complicated stuff like VPA. Please let us know what the problem is!

Answer (score 0):

If you have Symbolic Math Toolbox, there is a simple way to [increase arithmetics precision.](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/increase-precision-of-numeric-calculations.html)

As pointed on this webpage, take `vpa()` function from your inputs. You can either change the default precision by changing `digits` variable or specify the desired precision by the second argument in `vpa()` function